# How to calculate Fetching Time while fetching data from any Api in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1. I just want to show the amount of data  fetched  from  Api.
2. output should be like 10% fetched 90 % remaining  like that.
3. I'm searching how should I calculate the amount the amount retreived and remaning  data left to be fetched.
4. I have  been working on  basecamp api  It would  waste lots of time to fetch tasks , activities etc.
   So just want that I want to show time left  while fetching in Ajax .

I have googled and found a link: [Monitoring_progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)
         but if any body could suggest to me where to start I would much appreciate.

Comment: What do you understand by `data` ? download/upload kind of data or ajax request data ?

Comment: response from server ,  i have been working in api of basecamp it take lots of time to fetched tasks , activities  so i want to show user time so user be clamn to watch that.

Comment: download  ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get the exact time, but you can get an approximation.

#### Why you can't have an exact time ?

Most of the time is spent in the `basecamp` servers, not in the request. The link you posted offers a way for `basecamp` to push progress messages. If they don't do so, you will get nothing.

You can imagine the `basecamp` servers as a wall. Behind the wall is the progress, but you can't see behind a wall and you are not allowed by `basecamp` to climb it.

#### What to do ?

You can approximate this time. With a method similar to what is posted here:

```
var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
});
```

you can measure how long it will take to complete a request.

Than you calculate the `mean time` of all requests made to an `url`. That time will be good enough.

I recommend something like this:

- Measure times by yourself for every request, 10 times.
- Calculate the mean of the times ( sum them and divide by 10 (the number of requests))
- Save the result and send it when you initiate your application and store in the browser.
- When user makes request, get the precalculated time and display a timer.

#### Update

To display a fix amount of time as a percent you can do like this:

- `secondsPerPercent = timeInSeconds / 100` <-- this is how many seconds need to pass for a percent to be filled.
- make a javascript timer (code for it can be found on google) that updates the percent every `secondsPerPercent`.

Comment: plaese suggest if how could i implement this to show in progess baar like 10% fetched  like that